# Smart Packages from Atmosphere not added

Tags: meteor

I created the app in meteor but when adding the local package it added successfully but when  I try to add the package from "Atmosphere" like cookies, nodetime,jade-handlebars my terminal just act nothing. Please help me out guys.
I am using the meteor version 0.6.4 and meteorite version 0.6.5
Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you install the package with something like `mrt add cookies --verbose` does it give more useful error messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just figure out my solution. Any one those faces the same problem can get `"mrt add [some package] --repoPort=443"` it works perfect for me....for node 0.10.12.
YOu can get some help from https://github.com/oortcloud/meteorite/issues/155 also.